# How to index two tables for JOINed query optimisation

Tags: postgresql, join, index-tuning

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 on High Sierra.

Over the two tables:

```
request_logs - ~ 26K rows

response_logs - ~ 9K rows
```

I've the following query (with JOIN):

```
SELECT
  req.uuid,
  res.status,
  req.method,
  req.requesturi,
  req.accessed,
  req.payload reqpayload, 
  res.payload respayload,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows
FROM
  request_logs req
  LEFT OUTER JOIN response_logs res ON req.uuid = res.uuid
WHERE
   req.accountid = 2 AND
   req.requesturi not ilike '/v1/sessions%' AND
   req.accessed BETWEEN “2018-01-01 15:04:05 +0000” and “2019-01-02 15:04:05+0000” AND
   res.status IS NOT NULL AND
   req.applicationid = 1
ORDER BY
   accessed DESC LIMIT 1000
```

As I'm trying to optimise the query, I've experimented with different indexes:
Here's a list of what I tried:

```
Configuration 1:
 1. request_log.uuid (pkey, unique)
 2. response_log.uuid (pkey, unique, foreign key)

Response time avg. : 260 ms
```

```
Configuration 2:
 1. request_log.uuid (pkey, unique)
 2. request_log.applicationid
 3. response_log.uuid (pkey, unique, foreign key)

Response time avg. : 230 ms
```

```
Configuration 3:
 1. request_log.uuid (pkey, unique)
 2. request_log.applicationid
 3. request_log.accessed (timestampz)
 4. response_log.uuid (pkey, unique, foreign key)

Response time avg. : 230 ms
```

```
Configuration 4:
 1. request_log.uuid (pkey, unique)
 2. request_log.applicationid
 3. request_log.accessed (timestampz)
 4. request_log.accountid
 5. response_log.uuid (pkey, unique, foreign key)

Response time avg. : 230 ms
```

```
Configuration 5:
 1. request_log.uuid (pkey, unique)
 2. request_log.applicationid, request_log.accessed (combined)
 3. response_log.uuid (pkey, unique, foreign key)

Response time avg. : 240 ms
```

As visible from the result, indexing by `applicationid` (an `int8`) did help a little, while indexing by the `timestampz` `accessed` didn't help at all. 
Maybe the bad performance is due to the JOIN?
Altogether, it seems quite slow and I try not to think what will happen when these tables contain millions of record (10M+).

What would be a better way to index these tables to make this query run faster?

EDIT:

Here is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the last configuration:

```
Limit  (cost=3489.80..3490.69 rows=356 width=823) (actual time=241.152..241.345 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=3489.80..3490.69 rows=356 width=823) (actual time=241.150..241.288 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: req.accessed DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 2064kB
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1829.41..3474.71 rows=356 width=823) (actual time=230.040..237.993 rows=3951 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1829.41..3470.26 rows=356 width=823) (actual time=8.622..17.974 rows=3951 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (res.uuid = req.uuid)
                    ->  Seq Scan on response_logs res  (cost=0.00..1604.21 rows=8821 width=758) (actual time=0.006..4.527 rows=9124 loops=1)
                          Filter: (status IS NOT NULL)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1816.39..1816.39 rows=1042 width=102) (actual time=8.243..8.243 rows=4046 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096 (originally 2048)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1122kB
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on request_logs req  (cost=105.85..1816.39 rows=1042 width=102) (actual time=0.581..6.449 rows=4046 loops=1)
Execution time: 242.154 ms
```

Comment: Please provide at least the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` of your statements

Comment: Thanks. The only thing i can see from the output is, that a Index on `response_logs.status` may help, if there are many entries with `NULL`. Also it may be wise to test indexes on all columns used in `WHERE`. I think i have to ask for `\d` of both tables or an http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The LEFT OUTER JOIN tells to add rows with null fields representing `res` entries that don't match the join clause, but the `res.status IS NOT NULL` clause tells to remove them. What you probably want is an INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: The next thing that might go is `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`. Do you really need every row to contain the total number of rows? Most interfaces that call a SELECT query know the number of rows from the metadata (i.e. `PQntuples()` in C).

Comment: You provided *some* good information. More is essential for performance optimization. Consider instructions in the tag info for [postgresql-performance]. In particular: `CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints, relevant value frequencies, avg row size. How selective is each `WHERE` condition? Which of these conditions are immutable? How do others vary? What is `res.status IS NOT NULL` supposed to achieve? Like @Daniel I suspect it's *wrong*, but the other way round, you may need to move it to the join condition of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @DanielVérité: `count(*) OVER()` computes the total count *before* `LIMIT` is applied. `PQntuples()` returns the number of rows actually returned. Only the same while the total count happens to be <= `LIMIT`. Still, would help performance a lot to get rid of it, especially if your tables grow to 10M+ rows. Maybe it's good enough to use `LIMIT 1001`, only use the first 1000 rows, check the row count and if it's 1001 you know there are "more than 1000 hits".

Comment: And why the odd illegal typographic double quotes in your query string? Please make sure to provide a valid query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter @DanielVérité Indeed `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows` is needed since we also need it in the response due to some architectural decisions. When the dataset is very big, we indeed omit `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows` and query for `LIMIT 1001` to see if there are "more than 1000 hits".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter the funny quotes are due to copy-paste. The actual query uses correct quotes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter furthermore, the only 'moving parts' in this  query are the dates (from and to) that are compared with `accessed`, `applicationid` and `accountid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, get your `LEFT JOIN` right and try to get rid of total rows (as discussed in comments):

#### Query

Updated to your comment:

> I only want to returns rows from `request_logs` that have a parallel entry in `response_logs` with non nil status:

```
SELECT q.uuid
     , s.status
     , q.method
     , q.requesturi
     , q.accessed
     , q.payload reqpayload
     , s.payload respayload
--   , COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows  -- see below
FROM   request_logs q
JOIN   response_logs s USING (uuid)   -- not LEFT JOIN
WHERE  q.accountid = 2
AND    q.requesturi NOT ILIKE '/v1/sessions%'
AND    q.accessed BETWEEN '2018-01-01 15:04:05 +0' AND '2019-01-02 15:04:05+0'
AND    q.applicationid = 1
AND    s.status IS NOT NULL           -- see below
ORDER  BY q.accessed DESC
LIMIT  1001;                          -- see below
```

Your `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` burns down to a plain `[INNER] JOIN`. Related:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

`COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows` is expensive for counts substantially bigger than `LIMIT` (and you are expecting "10m+ rows"). Maybe it's good enough to use `LIMIT 1001`, only use the first 1000 rows, check the row count and if it's 1001 then you know there are "more than 1000 matching rows". Related:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888375/run-a-query-with-a-limit-offset-and-also-get-the-total-number-of-rows/28888696#28888696)

#### Indexes

***If*** (like you commented)

> the only 'moving parts' in this query are the dates (from and to) that are compared with accessed

... and more than a few rows are excluded with the other predicates
on `applicationid`, `requesturi` and `accountid`, then a **partial index** should help read performance (a lot):

```
CREATE INDEX ON request_logs (uuid, accessed DESC)
WHERE  accountid = 2
AND    requesturi NOT ILIKE '/v1/sessions%'
AND    applicationid = 1
```

And if a substantial percentage of rows is eliminated by `status IS NOT NULL`, also:

```
CREATE INDEX ON response_logs (uuid)
WHERE  status IS NOT NULL;
```

It *may* pay to append the columns `status` and `payload` as index columns if you can get [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) out of it. Some preconditions apply.

Comment: Actually, I only want to returns rows from `request_logs` that have a parallel entry in `response_logs` with non nil `status`.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to `LIMIT 1001` - that's a good approach and I use it when the table is very big.

Comment: @AlexGordon: I adapted to your updates.

Comment: I did update the indexes as you suggested and it did improve the performance a little bit. However, the main improvement was replacing `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`. Because the SELECT part specified a lot of items to be copied (mainly `respayload` and `reqpayload`), because of `OVER()`, the statement executed on the entire table and these columns were copied for the entire table, just to get the count, then discarded and  the query executed again. Replacing the `COUNT` part with a copy of this query and a minimal `SELECT` part improved the performance by factor of five!